# "Что в... что в" — употребляется ли?

Tags: грамотная-речь, союзы

Употребляется ли такой составной союз вместо *как.. так и?* Например:

> Я считаю, что необходимо знать правильное написание слов ***что в*** русском, ***что в*** английском.

Answer (score 4):

Словари фиксируют союз ***что..., что.***

Из "Толкового словаря" Т.Ф. Ефремовой:

> ***Что.., Что***
>
> **союз** разг. 1. Употр. при соединении однородных членов предложения или целых предложений, выступающих как равнозначные.
>
> https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/266707

Примеры из "Словаря наречий и служебных слов русского языка В.В. Бурцевой (М., 2010):

> *Мне всё равно, **что** ты мне поможешь, **что** она.*
>
> *Очень холодно, **что** в доме, **что** на улице.*

Из словаря Бурцевой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, Слава!

Answer (score 3):

Артем, как всегда, у вас интересный вопрос. В действительности союз ***ЧТО...ЧТО***  мы **довольно часто используем в речи**, причем не только в устойчивых выражениях вида «что в лоб, что по лбу; что летом, что зимой», но и  в обычных фразах, например: *Что флексия, что окончание – это ведь одно и то же*.

**А каков статус этого союза?** Нам кажется, что этот союз синонимичен союзу ***КАК...ТАК И***, потому что он может заменять его. Но это не совсем так.
***КАК...ТАК И*** – это нормированный  в грамматике союз, он относится к **двойным (градационным) союзам** и обозначает соединительно-сопоставительные отношения.
Близок к нему по значению повторяющийся **союз *И...И***, который от обычного соединительного союза отличается **подчеркиванием** каждого однородного члена. Как будто всё так же: союз ***ЧТО...ЧТО***  тоже соединяет, сопоставляет, подчеркивает.

Тем не менее союз ***ЧТО...ЧТО***, как мне думается, выражает еще **дополнительную семантику,** которую можно обозначить словами «неважно, нет разницы» и которая отсутствует в названных выше союзах. Поэтому этот союз имеет **определенные ограничения.** Но используется в языке он давно, есть примеры из классики. Так почему же ваше предложение назвали неудачным?

***Я считаю, что необходимо знать правильное написание слов что в русском, что в английском**.*

Действительно, чувствуется стилистическая **некорректность**. Давайте попробуем его переделать, как вам такой вариант: ***Хороший словарный запас нужен в любом языке, что в русском, что в английском.*** По-моему, звучит нормально.

А что не так было в первом предложении? Я могу предположить, что  **дополнительная семантика обычно указывается**, а исключение делаются для достаточно устойчивых выражений вида «что зимой, что летом».  Поэтому надо добавить **слово «любой»**, то есть всякий, каждый, какой угодно на выбор. Такой вывод можно сделать, просмотрев реальные предложения из Нацкорпуса:

**Не всё ли равно**, что сегодня, что через три дня…» [И. А. Гончаров. (1842)]

**Идти все одно**, что вперед, что назад, а идти надо, решили мы и ночь провели за осмотром одежды своей и снаряжения. [Л. К. Артамонов (1899)]

Температура воздуха что зимой, что летом ― в среднем сорок градусов. [Михаил Ходаренок, 2001]

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Еще мне не нравится пример из словаря: ***Мне всё равно, что ты мне поможешь, что она.***
Мне кажется, что этот союз может соединять однородные члены, а вот с предложениями у него как-то не очень получается.

Comment: Полностью согласен с положением, что с союзом "что... что" обычно требуется _явное_ присутствие дополнительной семантики, указывающей на _отсутствие различия_. Без этого он как бы повисает в воздухе (подобно изолированно употребленному "в том числе" из современного журналистского просторечия).

Comment: Спасибо большое! Мне всё-таки кажется, что без этой дополнительной семантики можно обойтись — вот ведь её нету в последнем вашем примере.

Comment: Артем, в последнем примере дополнительная семантика указана  конкретно - сорок градусов, то есть одна и та же. Кстати, а вы свое предложение  считаете стилистически корректным? Если нет, то почему?

Comment: Alex_ander, а вам нравится, как этот союз соединяет предложения? Я привожу пример в Дополнении к ответу.

Answer (score 0):

Не думаю, что есть такой составной (точнее, двойной или парный) союз. Есть союз *что*, который при повторении соединяет однородные члены предложения и подчёркивает их одинаковость. Примеры из словаря Кузнецова: *что в лоб, что по лбу;* *что в доме, что на улице;* *что ночью, что днём по дороге не проехать*. Сфера возможного применения такого употребления союза "что" значительно уже, чем парного союза *как... так и*, который выражает перечисление. В частности, употребление его в рассматриваемом в вопросе примере не выглядит уместным.